# How to ignore unused_local_variable warning for the entire project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a few variables that I am not using/referring to anywhere in the project so I am getting a `unused_local_variable` warning.

Currently I am using

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_local_variable
```

to ignore those warning for that file but I have many files and I don't want to write the same in each one of them. So, how can I suppress this warning for the entire project?

Adding this to `analysis_options.yaml` file didn't work:

```
linter:
  rules:
     unused_local_variable: false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unused_local_variables` isn't a lint rule (it's not listed by https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules or in https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/blob/main/example/all.yaml), so disabling it under `linter: rules:` will have no effect.

`unused_local_variables` instead is an analyzer code.  Per https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#ignoring-rules, you can edit your `analysis_options.yaml` file and add:

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    unused_local_variable: ignore
```

That said, *really* you should just get rid of your unused local variables.